# How to Determine Exception Subtype

Tags: vb.net, exception

I'm wondering if there's a standard way to determine the sub-type of an exception. For example, for the [`File.Copy()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9706cfs5(v=vs.110).aspx) method, `IOException` indicates that the destination file exists **OR** a general I/O error occurred. There are other such cases. In my exception handler, how can I determine which it is? I'm checking the end of `ex.Message` for the string `already exists.`, which works, but seems awfully kludgy and unreliable.

While it is possible to check [`File.Exists()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists(v=vs.110).aspx) on the destination file, confirm overwrite with the user if it exists and then perform `File.Copy()` this is not atomic, which is to say, between checking and copying, it is possible for the conditions to change, for example if some other process created or copied a file into the destination location.

EDIT:
I had already changed the code based on comments here, but I just rolled it back and will post it here, just to show what I was doing:

```
        Try
            File.Copy(SrcFile, DstFile, OverWrite)

        Catch ex As DirectoryNotFoundException
            MsgBox(ex.Message)

        Catch ex As FileNotFoundException
            MsgBox("File not found: " & ex.FileName)

        Catch ex As UnauthorizedAccessException
            MsgBox("You do not have write access to the destination.")

        Catch ex As IOException
            ' IOException represents an existing destination file OR a general IO error.
            If SubStr(ex.Message, -15) = "already exists." Then
                OverwriteCheck = MsgBox(
                "Overwrite " & IO.Path.GetFileName(SrcFile) & " in destination directory?",
                MsgBoxStyle.YesNo
                )
                If OverwriteCheck = DialogResult.Yes Then
                    Try
                        File.Copy(SrcFile, DstFile, OverWrite)
                    Catch iex As Exception
                        MsgBox("Unable to copy " & SrcFile & ":" & vbNewLine & iex.Message)
                    End Try
                End If
            Else
                Throw ex
            End If

        Catch ex As ArgumentException
            ' The user left a blank line in the text box. Just skip it.
        End Try
```

Comment: In your specific case, you should check if *destFileName exists and overwrite is **false***.

Comment: OK, check it directly with `File.Exists()` first, rather than relying on the exception? I guess I'll have to do that.

Comment: You should never rely on an exception as part of your program's logic when you can avoid it.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you. If you feel it's worthwhile, could you put all this in an answer?

Comment: @djv I just thought of something, though: `File.Exists()` -> `File.Copy()` is not atomic. Meh, close enough, I guess.

Comment: If the atomicity is a concern, you could lock the source file with a FileStream Using block, then Using another FileStream to open the destination, and use `FileStream.CopyTo(Stream)`. Inside the outer Using block you can perform your logic checks for file existence and whether overwrite is true. Kind of reinventing the wheel, but you would get the exception customization you're looking for.

Comment: OK, that makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: What difference does it make in terms of how you react?  Are you trying to give the user guidance on how to make the problem go away, or are you trying to take remedial action without notifying the user?  Note that there are other exceptions that could issue from file operations than `IOException`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an option using FileStreams to get more granular information about your exception

```
Sub Main()
    Try
        copyTo("C:\t\output3.txt", "C:\t\output1.txt", True)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
    End Try
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub

Private Sub copyTo(source As String, destination As String, Optional overwrite As Boolean = False)
   ' raises FileNotFoundException if source doesn't exist
    Using fsSource As New FileStream(source, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None)
        If Not overwrite AndAlso File.Exists(destination) Then
            ' Raises exception when destination file exists and not overwrite
            Throw New Exception(
                String.Format("Destination file '{0}' exists and overwrite is false.", destination))
        Else
            Using fsDestination As New FileStream(destination, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None)
                fsSource.CopyTo(fsDestination)
            End Using
        End If
    End Using
End Sub
```

This is a rudimentary example, but you can see how you can differentiate different exception cases, while having atomicity between checking file existence and copying.

Comment: +1 for a good general purpose method.  Now if the OP will edit his question to be about this specific question so that others might find it.  One other option,  on Windows at least, would be to check `System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetLastWin32Error` and create a lookup.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you looking for this pattern:

```
Try
    IO.File.Copy("source", "Dest", True)

Catch exUnAuth As System.UnauthorizedAccessException

Catch exArg As System.ArgumentException

Catch exNotFound As IO.FileNotFoundException

Catch exGeneral As System.Exception

End Try
```

Place the list of specific exceptions first in the sequence.  The last exception tested for should be the least derived.

You should read through the documentation: [How to use structured exception handling in Visual Basic .NET or in Visual Basic 2005](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/315965/how-to-use-structured-exception-handling-in-visual-basic--net-or-in-vi).  Yes this is an old reference, but that is an indication how long this has been part of the language.

Comment: Thank you, but it isn't a question of how to handle exceptions, rather the fact that some exceptions represent more than one possible situation. I do in fact have my exception handlers in that sequence, but `IOException` is ambiguous, even when I check the derived exceptions first.

Comment: @alanlittle, so your question is not about determining the exception type in terms normally used when discussing the .Net type system, but rather extracting meaning from the exception message when a specific exception does not exist/or is not thrown.

Comment: Well, the documentation says that `IOException` represents an existing destination file OR an I/O error. Even after checking the exceptions derived from `IOException`, that ambiguity still exists. However, see djv's comments above; I should check for the existing file first, rather than relying on the exception.

Comment: @alanlittle, while checking if the file exists before calling the `Copy` method appears to be an infallible idea, it can still fail if some other process deletes the file between the point that your code checks for it and the `Copy` tries to open the file.  This circumstance may not exist in your particular usage case, but be aware that it does happen in other cases.

Comment: Yes, that was what I realized: The operation is not atomic, especially since, if the file exists, I need to confirm overwrite with the user. See my comment to djv above. As you say, though, probably not an issue in this case. Thanks.